# Pseudo-element working on pc, then not working on mobile

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I have a pseudo-element that works on pc (min-width: 768px), but then it doesn't work on mobile.
I looked into it and found out that theoretically with `position: relative` the pseudo-element shouldn't listen to `height` and `width`.

Here's my code:

`(min-width: 768px)` works:

```
.progress-step:before {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      background-color: #7A7A7A;
      height: 0.4rem;
      width: 300%;
      position: relative;
      bottom: -31px;
      left: -218px;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }
```

mobile, doesn't work:

```
.progress-step:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background-color: #7A7A7A;
    height: 1rem;
    width: 0.4rem;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -31px;
    left: -218px;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
```

EDIT: note that the `.progress-step` on the first is set to `display: block` and the second is `display: flex`, but I read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) that `flex` behaves as `block`

EDIT2: Here are some screens:

::before highlighted:

[image: Here is the ::before highlighted]

`.progress-step` highlighted:

[image: Here is the .progress-step highlighted]

Comment: What exactly is it, that doesn't work?

Comment: Care to share screenshots. But going by the CSS, the positioning (left and bottom) might be throwing the element off screen.

Comment: @AndySukowski-Bang it doesn't recognize width

Comment: @crazychukz the problem is with the width, I can see from inspect that it has 0 width

Comment: Change width to ``px instead rem``

Comment: @Aman done, still not working

Comment: can you please provide the link or anything else???

Comment: @Aman included two screens

Comment: Please show more of the context - preferably a working snippet. How progress-step is set up is important. And also do you mean the width on mobile to be 0.4rem?